# Discord.js: interaction.reply not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot using discords javascript api and everything was working fine up until I got to 5 commands. I keep getting this same error messages and I'm not sure what's causing them. What's weird is that occasionally it works but when i restart the bot it stops working. I need some help finding and fixing this issue.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, EmbedBuilder, MessageAttachment, SlashCommandBuilder, PermissionsBitsField, Permissions, AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent] });

const server = require('./server.js')
const randomCat = require('random-cat-img');
const redditParse = require("redditparse");
const fs = require('fs');

const token = process.env['token']

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(client.user.tag + " online")
  client.user.setActivity('cooking meth')

  const ping = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('ping')
    .setDescription('This is a ping command')
  const kitten = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('kitten')
    .setDescription('Gives a random image of a cat')
  const pokemon = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('pokemon')
    .setDescription('Syntax: /pokemon *number here*')
    .addIntegerOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('number')
        .setDescription('Pokemon number')
        .setRequired(true))
  const meme = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('meme')
    .setDescription('Random memed from r/funny')
  const help = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('help')
    .setDescription('List every command')
  const bugreport = new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('bugreport')
    .setDescription('Report a bug')
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName('content')
        .setDescription('Bug')
        .setRequired(true))

  client.application.commands.create(ping)
  client.application.commands.create(kitten)
  client.application.commands.create(pokemon)
  client.application.commands.create(meme)
  client.application.commands.create(help)
  client.application.commands.create(bugreport)
})

client.on('interactionCreate', (interaction) => {
  if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
  if (interaction.commandName === 'ping') {
    interaction.reply('pong')
  }
  if (interaction.commandName === 'pokemon') {
    const number = interaction.options.getInteger('number')

    if (number > 721 || number < 1) {
      interaction.reply("This pokemon doesn't exist or is from generation 7 onwards")

      return
    } else {
      interaction.reply({ files: ['pokemon_jpg/' + number + '.jpg'] });
    }

  }
  if (interaction.commandName === 'kitten') {
    getKittenImage();

    async function getKittenImage() {
      let resultObject;
      do {
        const result = await redditParse.randomPost("cats");
        resultObject = JSON.parse(result);
      } while (resultObject.type != "image")
      console.log(resultObject)
      const kittenEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(resultObject.title)
        .setImage(resultObject.image)
        .setColor(0x93C54B)

      interaction.reply({
        embeds: [kittenEmbed]
      })
    };
  }
  if (interaction.commandName === 'meme') {
    getMemeImage();

    async function getMemeImage() {
      let resultObject;
      do {
        const result = await redditParse.randomPost("funny");
        resultObject = JSON.parse(result);
      } while (resultObject.type != "image")
      console.log(resultObject)
      const memeEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle(resultObject.title)
        .setImage(resultObject.image)
        .setColor(0x93C54B)

      interaction.reply({
        embeds: [memeEmbed]
      })
    };
  }
  if (interaction.commandName === 'help') {
    const helpEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("**Commands**")
      .setDescription("`/ping` - Testing purposes\n`/kitten` - Sends a random reddit picture of a cat\n`/pokemon` - Sends a picture of the pokemon associated with the given number\n`/meme` - Sends a random meme from reddit\n`/bugreport` - Report a bug\n\nHeisenburger v1.0")
      .setColor(0x93C54B);

    interaction.reply({
      embeds: [helpEmbed]
    })
  }
  if (interaction.commandName === 'bugreport') {
    const content = interaction.options.getString('content')
    fs.writeFile('bugs.txt', content + '\n', { flag: 'a+' }, err => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })
    interaction.reply('Done!')
  }
});

client.login(token)
```

As I said it only started malfunctioning when i reached 5 commands and sometimes it still works. I'm using discord.js v14 for this project.

Comment: Provide the error please